# Intellij-idea - module dependency not working in multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Multi Module Maven project is configured in Intellij. There are two modules - common and service. common dependency is added in the pom.xml of service module. `mvn clean install` is successful, still Intellij is showing compilation error on importing class in common module into a class of service module.

I tried various options, such as Reimport, Rebuild, Synchronize, `mvn clean install`, `mvn -U idea:idea`. But none works.

At last, it works after manually adding Module Depedency from Dependencies tab in Project Structure window.

How to configure Intellij to add module dependencies automatically?

Please find below the relevant code.

pom.xml of common module:

```
<project ...>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>common</name>
<groupId>myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

...
```

pom.xml of service module

```
...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

...
```

class com.common.Customer of common module.

```
package com.common;

public class Customer {
...
}
```

class com.service.CustManager of service module.

```
package com.service;

import com.common.Customer; // getting error in Itellij at this line.

public class CustManager {
...
}
```

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).